# What is a good alternative Google Fonts font to Samsung One?

Tags: font-recommendation, web-fonts, free

I'm going to give a Google Slides presentation to a small private group (this will **not** be used in public). It's related to Samsung, and so I wanted to use a font similar to their new typeface, SamsungOne. Is there any font available in Google Fonts that looks very similar to SamsungOne? I don't have to, but I thought it would be nice to have the font be based on the topic.

Comment: A simple google search will give you some websites to download it.

Comment: I know that, but as far as I know, there's no way to import custom fonts from files into Google Slides. Please let me know if there is, but I was hoping for a similar font that's part of Google Fonts.

Answer (score 1):

Roboto is pretty close

[image: Roboto vs SamsungOne]

This image was taken from the Verge: https://www.theverge.com/circuitbreaker/2016/7/25/12270938/samsung-font-samsungone-android-roboto